# Property is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
var my = {    
  vars: {
    name: 'mojo'
  },

  secondLevel: {
    vars: {
      name: my.vars.name
    }
  },
};

$("#myDiv").text(my.vars.name);
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MojoDK/Rf7j7/)

I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'vars' of undefined
```

Why can't I set `name: my.vars.name`?

Comment: You cannot self-reference an object literal as this does: `name: my.vars.name` (there is no `my` at the point of use) - [Self-references in object literal declarations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literal-declarations)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're accessing the variable that not yet have been created. Consider {} as constructor for an Object, so you're trying to work with object that have not yet been created. You can write it like this:

```
var my = {    
  vars: {
    name: 'mojo'
  },
  secondLevel: {
    vars: {}
  }
};

my.secondLevel.vars.name = my.vars.name;

$("#myDiv").text(my.vars.name);
```

By the way, why do you want that "second level" thing?

Comment: Ah ok I get it. Well I'm writing a huge js file (2000+ lines) and I want to have a section for vars in each "area", so vars doesn't get mixed and lose the overview.

Comment: @MojoDK, you might wanna consider closures: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work

Answer (score 0):

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rf7j7/2/)**

You can not use `.` in the names.

But also you have it round the wrong way if you did want it to work.

It should be like this:

```
var my = {    
    vars: {
        name: 'mojo'
    },

    secondLevel: {
        vars: {
            name: my_vars_name
        }
    },
};

 $("#myDiv").text(my_vars_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you get another error initially when js encounters your definition.

```
var my = {    
    vars: {
        name: 'mojo'
    },

    secondLevel: {
        vars: {
            name: my.vars.name//This is wrong. Use this.vars.name
        }
    },
};
```

> TypeError: my is undefined

you didn't notice this error. You cannot reference `my` in my declartion.

my is undefined because of this and therefore you cannot reference it.

Use `this` instead of my

```
name:this.vars.name
```